# Напишите программу-калькулятор, которая будет принимать на свой вход число

Tags: python

Напишите программу-калькулятор, которая будет принимать на свой вход число и будет выводить на экран по отдельности все его степени от 1 до 10, а также двойное и тройное значение введенного числа.
Я нашла все степени,а с двойным и тройным значением я не могу разобраться.Еще не очень понятно, что значит "двойное и тройное значение"?Как я понимаю, это найти все двузначные и трёхзначные числа из ряда чисел, полученных благодаря возведению в степени.

Всё,что у меня получилось:

```
t = int(input("Введите Ваше число:"))

print (t**1,t**2,t**3,t**4,t**5,t**6,t**7,t**8,t**9,t**10)
```

Comment: Нужно уточнять у тех, кто поставил задачу. Но мне кажется. что двойное и тройное означает умноженное на 2 и на 3 соответственно.

Comment: тогда было бы удвоенное или утроенное, кмк. здесь скорее всего два или три рядом стоящих числа. *ex:* 1 - 11, 111. хотя это тоже может быть не верно :)

Comment: а при чем здесь функциональное программирование?

Answer (score 1):

Ну если под двойным и тройным значением имеется ввиду умноженное на 2 или на 3 число, то получаем вот такой код:

```
n = int(input('Введите ваше число: '))
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(n**i, end=' ')
print(2*n, 3*n)
```

Если же имеется ввиду удвоенная запись числа (ну т.е. из 153 в 153153), то можно сделать так:

```
n = int(input('Введите ваше число: '))
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(n**i, end=' ')
print(str(n)*2, str(n)*3)
```